# Minecraft lags on a specific user

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a really great desktop machine that I use for all sorts of games - i7 cpu 8gb ram 2gb GTX 660 graphics card. I have different users because I have small children and different settings for them compared to the adults. On all of the logins Minecraft works totally fine, but on one of these logins, it just starts to lag and pause for no good reason. I can't figure it out. I've completely deleted the \user\appdata\roaming.minecraft folder and re-downloaded everything to do with it, but the same issue persists. I've updated to 1.6.1 today, but still no difference.

I have a Windows 8 installation, brand new, not many programs installed. I have 6 different users (4 Administrators, 2 normal users). I have tested Minecraft on 2 Administrator accounts and both the normal user accounts. All are fine except one normal user. I'm absolutely baffled so far...

I have a brand new installation of Windows 8, with really no programs running at all. I have far more in my start up for my user (sc2gears, dropbox, etc.) than the user with the issue. There just seems to be no rhyme or reason for it. The user in question is not an Administrator, which I thought could be the issue, but then there is another user who is not an Administrator, who runs Minecraft fine. It's a very confusing issue.

Comment: Sounds like this may be more of a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) if you do not get a satisfactory answer from here.

Comment: Windows, right?

Comment: Are you using multiple Windows logins, or multiple Minecraft installs on one Windows login?

Comment: Have you tried simply deleting that Windows user account and recreating it?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a program installed for only that user that is causing the slowdown. Go over the machine carefully with an antivirus program, check [`msconfig`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) for startup items for that user, and obvious things running in the system tray. It's highly likely a kid has installed something that is slowing down the system - malicious or otherwise.

Compare [Task Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/open-task-manager%E2%80%8E)'s process list for this user compared to others. Is there anything there that could be causing the slowdown?